# How can I specify environment variables on the client side for graphql?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql

For context, I am running graphql on my application. This application utilizes SSR (serverside rendering) and all the calls in that respect are working fine. When the client hits the application, I render the app, like any other standard react app:

`render(Routes, createClient())`

The problem is.. in create client (where the apolloclient is created, which tells the provider how to connect to the external graphql server), I reference an env variable.

```
const serverLocation =
  process.env.SERVER_LOCATION || 'http://localhost:8080/graphql
```

Now, this is all fine on the server in the SSR case, but there is no notion of an env variable on the client - just undefined. Given that this value can be configurable and gets instantiated on the client, how should I be populating this?

Comment: In short, you can't use envvars from the client machine. Instead you need to build the code that is eventually served to the client to include those variables as they are set on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do this. Essentially you want to somehow read the environment variables at compile-time and bake them into the compiled JS files that ultimately run on the client side.

One way to achieve this for a React app using webpack is to use a custom plugin:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = (env) => {
  // Create an object from the env variable
  const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
    return prev;
  }, {});

  return {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
    ]
  };
};
```

This will provide your client-side code with access to `process.env` variables.

Source (and some alternative solutions): https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5

Edit: since this is a pretty common scenario, this is how you would do the same using a `.env` file.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

module.exports = (env) => {
  const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

  // Create an object from the env variable
  const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
    return prev;
  }, {});

  return {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
    ]
  };
};
```

Comment: Ah, ok this is making a lot of sense. How should I be grabbing the actually env mappings at compile time? Given that this will probably be dockerized and configurable

Comment: or just pass them via --env in webpack?

Comment: In that case use the npm package dotenv - this allows you to provide a `.env` file in the root of your source that can contain all of your environment variables. The article I linked explains how to connect this `.env` file up with webpack (I just wanted to keep the answer fairly generic).